# How to add a Lock sign to .cs in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I forked a CrossFilePicker from github and added a new implementation that doesn't have a lock sign to the left of it, It feels like my file doesn't follow the project "implementation-lock" convention, is there a way to add it?

[image]

Comment: Looks like you forgot to clone the project from source control.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/version-control/git-clone-repository?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lock icon simply means your file is checked in, i.e. no change to that file compared to the HEAD:

[image]

If you add/delete/modify a file, the icon would change to reflect that. If you want a lock, stage that file and make a commit.